# Failed resolution of: Lcom/facebook/internal/LoginAuthorizationType

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I have an android app with Facebook login implemented. It has been working perfect for the last year, but today I started my app and got an error on this line:

```
final LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.facebook_login_button);
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile,email"));
```

Error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.application.GlassFrogg, PID: 28151
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/facebook/internal/LoginAuthorizationType;
    at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$LoginButtonProperties.setReadPermissions(LoginButton.java:149)
    at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.setReadPermissions(LoginButton.java:276)
    at com.application.GlassFrogg.LoginScreen.onCreate(LoginScreen.java:184)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7317)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3066)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3229)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.internal.LoginAuthorizationType" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        ... 18 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm64) /data/app/com.application.GlassFrogg-9iEMWqfIsuzThI_-Q3q51w==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
    at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:764)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:847)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1088)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2563)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6031)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:235)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1768)
            ... 6 more
```

For some reason I am getting three errors when the app crashes. A google search for the exact error code gave me 0 results (that was a first).

I have tried to change what read permissions I request do no avail. I checked to see if methods have been depreciated in the recent facebook API updated, but I don't think that is the issue either.

Comment: hey how did you fix it ?

Comment: deleted that line of code for now...

Comment: Did you add facebook share into your project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by updating to the latest version of the Facebook API. Some of the function calls changed slightly in the update which was causing the crash.